# How Can I add data attribute to script tag using Nuxt Js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

```
<script src="https://js.sample.js/fetchsample" data-cb-site="your-site"   
 data-cb-fbq-enabled="true"> 
</script>
```

I have this script.
in nuxt js we have this kind of structure

```
 script: [
{src: "https://js.sample.js/fetchsample" , data-cb-site="your site",  data-cb-fbq-enabled="true" }
]
```

But I am getting an error on adding that data-cb-ste and data-cb-fbq-enabled data attribute .
Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
  at new Script (vm.js:86:7)
  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a hint in the SyntaxError you are getting:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

The dash `-` is not allowed in property names outside of quotes.

So you need to change `data-cb-site` to `"data-cb-site"` where you define it in the object literal.

And when you access fields with a dash `-` in the name, you must use square-bracket notation, e.g. `object["data-cb-site"]` not `object.data-cb-site`.

```
script: [
  {
    src: "https://js.sample.js/fetchsample", 
    "data-cb-site": "your site",
    "data-cb-fbq-enabled": "true"
  }
]
```

Comment: @isherwood Actually it is the typing mistake while posting a question.@sdgluck answer is working fine.

Comment: Still, there's no explanation about what the operative change was. I assume it was the quotation marks on the keys (possibly necessary due to the hyphens), but that should be stated.